# ERROR Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native after upgrade to sdk 46

Tags: react-native, expo

I have upgraded my expo app to SDK 46 from 38.
now I get the above error. I have gone through stack answers but most of the solutions refer to index.js which I couldn't find in my project.
use my package json to see any errors need to be fixed.

Any help would be much appreciated.
[image]

package JSON

```
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.0-alpha.25",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.0.0-alpha.27",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.0.0-alpha.35",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.0.0-alpha.22",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0-alpha.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^5.0.0-alpha.16",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0-alpha.43",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.0",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-app-auth": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.7.1",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-background-fetch": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-cellular": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-network": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.2.0",
    "expo-random": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.5",
    "expo-web-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-picker-select": "3.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-stopwatch-timer": "0.0.21",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.14.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: please show your package.json file as well

Comment: do you use ViewPropType in any of your code by any chance?

Comment: nothing as i'm aware of

Comment: any chance to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the installed packages. To solve it try uninstalling, react-native-unimodules and react-native-stopwatch timer. Remove them from your source code and see if it works!